# Software for learning pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation

Is there some kind of program/app like Duolingo for learning pronunciation of the English language?

With consistent use of English as a written medium, you cannot not get better (in most cases), but how to improve pronunciation without studying/reading phonetic notation?

Comment: You can go to Google Translate, which has an audible pronunciation feature. Depending on your locale settings, it will be British or American pronunciation. It's fairly accurate with individual words, but intonation patterns for longer phrases can sometimes be off.

Comment: Read my reply to @Generalbrus.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14448/english-pronunciation-software-for-a-learner

Comment: You might also take a look at the software recommendations SE. Last time I searched there were a number of recommendations for language learning software.

Comment: You can try http://epronunciation.com/pronunciation
for basic pronunciation lesson.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my personal experience I believe the best way to learn the correct pronunciation (and improve your English in general) is by watching movies/videos and listening to the radio. That helps aquire a specific accent as well.

Comment: I do get that, but if you have used Duolingo for learning another language from English (i.e. English to German) you'll see that they have you talk in some sentences to test that you actually can pronounce it. You don't get the same feedback by watching movies and listening to radio.

Comment: @MrJensenn Well, my mom uses Babbel to improve her pronunciation. She listens to chunks of conversations and then she repeats them recording herself. I don't know Duolingo or any other apps so I wouldn't know if it's what you're looking for :)

Comment: Radio is fine, but dialects in movies can be ambiguous, not to mention misleading.

Comment: @MARamezani I guess if we're going there, a student trying to exactly mimic the intonation used by a radio DJ is going to end up sounding pretty odd, too. :) In either case, though, I think they would sound better than if they never watched movies or listened to the radio.

Answer (score 0):

1. To “movies and the radio” I’d add audio books. The readers tend to speak clearly. When you can afford it, you can get the audio book, the printed English book and the printed book in your language, and compare them.
2. To toot my own horn a bit, ([**BRAAAAAAP!**](https://xkcd.com/757/)) try [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/) with my [audio download](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/3100585138) add-on. It should find English pronunciations for most words.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most important tools you can use in working on pronunciation is a small mirror.  Use it to check the shape of your mouth, what your teeth and tongue are doing, etc. -- but only focus on your mouth.  It is too distracting to have your eyes, etc., in view.