# What is best approach for learning language?

Tags: british-english, learning-methods

I was banned in `Stackoverflow`as mentioned in [I](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302148/360111) and [II](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357876/6792573) posts.

One of major issues due that, is my English knowledge. Therefore [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) guided me here in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46746994/6792573).

With regard [Free live online English assessment test for IELT/TOEFL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/117326/63187), [Online Resources for Learning English](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/2931/63187) and [Software for learning pronunciation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/49893/63187) posts, I'm looking for suitable approach for learning English.

As I have using `www.freecodecamp.org` courses service for learning programming, is there a same opportunity for learning English language?

For an example as an assumed approach, (if this approach is true):
**Is there any non profit resources, which is available as a online learning English Language (English Accent) free website?**

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because requests for resources are off-topic. Please see the [help/on-topic] and [_Resources for learning English_](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english).

Comment: Welcome to ELL! You may want to look over [What topics can I ask about?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for some guidance about what questions are on-topic here. You may also want to check out [chat] if you have English questions that don't fit within those guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's such a thing as "the best approach", the best thing you can do is try as many methods as possible and then create the perfect system for you. Regardless, one of the resources the helped the most when I started learning English was the Engvid YouTube channel and their affiliated channels. Audiobooks are great too, start with books with simple languages like children books or young-adult and then as your English improves you can venture into fantasy and sci-fi.

For formal and technical vocabulary I like to read articles on Medium and The New Yorker. I particularly don't consider English online courses really effective when learning English, for me my most valuable allies when learning English were/are YouTube, Netflix, Audible, and Google to clear up my doubts.